# how to get latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, geocoding

I tried to make a prayer schedule application, but I got a problem when the system wanted to get latitude and longitude values, in the initial program I had put the manifest permissions to enable GPS in the main activity

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UtamaActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UtamaActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},44);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},44);
            } else {
                Intent jadwalSholat = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimePrayActivity.class);
                startActivity(jadwalSholat);
            }
        }
    });
```

I have added **ACCESS_FINE** and **ACCESS_COARSE** permissions to the manifest, but when going to activity time prayer, the GPS does not automatically activate, the user must manually activate the GPS, even though the GPS and internet connection have been activated, the program still does not get the latitude and longitude values.

TimePrayActivity:

```
    public class JadwalSholatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    FusedLocationProviderClient providerClient;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private static final int ACCESS_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jadwal_sholat);

        ...
        providerClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.barbar);

        checkState();

    }

    private void checkState(){
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null){
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Enable your GPS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    getLocation();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void getLocation(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        providerClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                Location location = task.getResult();
                if (location != null){
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(JadwalSholatActivity.this,Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
                        latitude = (double) addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                        longitude = (double) addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
                        jadwalSholat();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void jadwalSholat(){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        DateComponents dateComponents = DateComponents.from(new Date());
        **Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude,longitude);**
        CalculationParameters parameters = CalculationMethod.MUSLIM_WORLD_LEAGUE.getParameters();

        SimpleDateFormat formats = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        formats.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        PrayerTimes prayerTimes = new PrayerTimes(coordinates,dateComponents,parameters);

        ...
    }
}
```

So, the problem I get is, most likely, the program doesn't get longitude and latitude values, if there are other problems please tell them in the comments

Comment: The `addOnCompleteListener` is called? If so, did you check if the task was successful ? `task.isSuccessful()` ? Do you want to receive locations updates or just the LastLocation?

Comment: what I want is the last location of the user, well I will try to add the successfull task condition. Thanks a lot